# blender 2.80 - particle system makes object not renderable

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

in my scene I have a problem with my tree object. Whenever I apply a particle system to it, it's not rendered anymore. You can download the file here:

[image]

Has someone an idea, what's going on here?

Any tip is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: In particle settings -> Render -> ON the option  "Show Emitter", that allows Blender to render also the base object (particle emitter).

Comment: Thank you very much! I never realized that option.